# Calendar not returning correct month

Tags: java, android

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
String monthName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

Log.d("monthName: ", monthName);
```

In this piece of code, I am trying to get the name of a month depending on it's number. In this example I want to log the month February from it's number, however in this example it logs `Mar` instead of `Feb`.

Why doesn't this work? `Feb`'s index is 1, isn't it?

Comment: The numbered months start at 0, not 1, with a `Calendar`.

Comment: Yes, so January is 0 and February is 1. But when I put 1 in my code I get March! @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: the problem that you have is that today is 30th. February does not have 30th. You have to set `Calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)` in order to get the correct date. Happy new year